# Can Git clone a branch excluding submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two Git repositories for the same project, one has submodules but another one doesn't have.

- Repository1 : has a submodule and tracks the changes in submodule
- Repository2 : doesn't have anything about the submodule

How can I configure two repositories to sync up the common parts excluding the submodule?

I think merging a branch on repository2 to repository1 doesn't matter but merging in the opposite way does since commits associated with the submodule will be fetched.

Is it possible to clone a branch **excluding all the configurations and commits regarding sumodules**?

I've found options for including/updating submodules such as `--recurse-submodules`, but couldn't find any option excluding submodules.

Is there any way to ignore submodules when cloning using Git?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's simply the default: submodules are not fetch neither cloned when cloning a repository with submodules.

Comment: I want the submodule to be tracked from the parent repository, but the cloned repository should not know about anything about the submodule. Would it be possible?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible: submodules are tracked via the committed file '.gitmodules' so any clone will have this file and submodules information. You can only ignore them by not launching any submodule-related command or option.